# NoSuchMethodError on Spark applications

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

I ran an application on `Spark cluster` but it gave me an `error` like this  :

```
     14/11/20 21:59:08 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 11.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 64, spark1): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.limit(Ljava/io/InputStream;J)Ljava/io/InputStream;        org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalAppendOnlyMap$DiskMapIterator.nextBatchStream(ExternalAppendOnlyMap.scala:456)        
     org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalAppendOnlyMap$DiskMapIterator.<init>  (ExternalAppendOnlyMap.scala:428)        org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalAppendOnlyMap.spill(ExternalAppendOnlyMap.scala:235)        org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalAppendOnlyMap.insertAll(ExternalAppendOnlyMap.scala:150)
    org.apache.spark.Aggregator.combineValuesByKey(Aggregator.scala:58)
    org.apache.spark.shuffle.hash.HashShuffleReader.read(HashShuffleReader.scala:48)        
    org.apache.spark.rdd.ShuffledRDD.compute(ShuffledRDD.scala:92)
    org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:262)
    org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:229)
    org.apache.spark.rdd.MappedRDD.compute(MappedRDD.scala:31)
    org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:262)
    org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:229)
    org.apache.spark.rdd.MappedRDD.compute(MappedRDD.scala:31)
    org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:262)
    org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:229)
    org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:62)
    org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:54)
    org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:177)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Could someone tells me how to fix it?

Comment: `NoSuchMethodError` typically signals a version issue. Are your workers running the same Spark version than the one you used to compile your job?

Comment: All of workers using Spark1.1, but some of them using jdk 1.7_67, the others using jdk 1.7_71. Does that matter?

Comment: the issue is with Google Guava versions. Probably some version conflict with a library or different Spark versions. You need to evaluate your dependencies and review your deployment.

Comment: I checked the log again and found an ERROR in the bottom of call stack:14/11/23 13:09:46 ERROR BlockFetcherIterator$BasicBlockFetcherIterator: Error occurred while fetching local blocks
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/spark-local-20141123130123-2692/0c/shuffle_0_20_88 (No such file or directory) @maasg

Answer (score 3):

Incompatible Google Guava library version precedes in its runtime class path. I suggest to clarify types of this case and tackle it:

**Case 1: Problem in Project Dependency**

As you're using maven, `maven dependency:tree` can tell all dependencies in your libraries. If you see multiple Google Guava versions, then please fix that by adding `<exclusion>` tag to the library dependency which depends on the incompatible Guava version.

**Case 2: Problem in Runtime Environment**

If your dependencies are correct, then the problem is in CLASSPATH of your runtime environment, where incompatible version of Google Guava library precedes desirable version. Although I haven't tried this, I see spark has experimental `spark.files.userClassPathFirst` configuration (link below). This may resolve your problem.
https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the spark uses old guava version - 14.0.1. Looks like some of you dependencies bring newer version of guava. Just force to use 14.0.1 in you build tool and everything should be fine

Comment: If so, that would not solve the problem, right? 14 doesn't work for this user code.

Comment: @1esha We checked our library which built by maven, the guava version it brought into our project is 14.0.1...

Comment: @fanhk do you use spark standalone cluster or mesos/yarn?

Comment: @1esha Spark on yarn.